# Edge Animate composition won't open, "Loading Failed, please check your page for javascript errors"

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

When I try to open my Edge Animate .an project I get the error message "Loading Failed, Please Check your page for Javascript Errors". I tried the suggestions in this page http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/2012/01/04/why-cant-it-just-work/ as suggested in other sites, but it doesn't detect any errors in both Dreamweaver or a browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What saved me from re-doing my whole project was the advice found in this site:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1883220

You have to look under your PROJECT_edge.js file in any text editor, and you will probably find duplicated lines in the fonts area. Delete duplicates (make sure you don't erase anything else and that you don't cause syntax errors) and you are good to go! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I found a resolution the the "JavaScript Error" preventing me from opening my .an file.

It seems like the same edge font was declared twice within the .js, I removed the second declaration and my .an file loaded. I would recommend checking that out

```
    fonts = {
        'source-sans-pro, sans-serif': '<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n4,n9,n7,i7,i4,n3,i3,n6,i6,i9,n2,i2:all.js"></script>',
        'source-sans-pro, sans-serif': '<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n4,n9,n7,i7,i4,n3,i3,n6,i6,i9,n2,i2:all.js"></script>'        },

    fonts = {
        'source-sans-pro, sans-serif': '<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n4,n9,n7,i7,i4,n3,i3,n6,i6,i9,n2,i2:all.js"></script>'        },
```